# Find Coefficient in expansion of $(x-1)^k(x+1)^{d-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, closed-form

While thinking about a problem relating to the [bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform), I came across the following question:

> Given $p$ with $0 \leq p \leq d$, find the coefficient of $x^p$ in the expansion $(x-1)^k(x+1)^{d-k}$.

Ideally, I'd like an answer in some closed form. Here are my thoughts so far: after taking a "brute force" approach via binomial expansion, I have found that
$$
(x-1)^k(x+1)^{d-k} = \sum_{p=0}^d \left[\sum_{j=0}^{d-k} (-1)^{k+j-p} 
\binom{k}{p-j} \binom{d-k}{j}
\right]x^p,
$$
which I wasn't able to simplify further.  So, our coefficient should be equal to $\sum_{j=0}^{d-k} (-1)^{k+j-p} 
\binom{k}{p-j} \binom{d-k}{j}$.

Another thought is to compute the coefficient as $\frac 1{p!} f_{k,d}^{(p)}(0)$, where $f_{k,d}(x) = (x-1)^k(x+1)^{d-k}$.  Taking derivatives leads to the interesting recurrence
$$
f_{k,d}' = kf_{k-1,d-1} + (d-k)f_{k,d-1}.
$$
So in other words, if $c^p_{k,d}$ denotes the desired coefficient, then we have
$$
c_{k,d}^p = \frac 1{p!}f^{(p)}_{k,d}(0) = 
\frac{k}{p!}f_{k-1,d-1}^{(p-1)} + \frac{d-k}{p!}f_{k,d}^{(p-1)}\\
=\frac{k}{p}c_{k-1,d-1}^{p-1} + \frac{d-k}{p}c_{k,d-1}^{p-1}.
$$
I wasn't able to see a clear path forward from there. Any ideas here would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have hope for something simpler than a hypergeometric function expression?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Not necessarily. If the best I can do is an expression in terms of hypergeometric functions then I'd be happy with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can show elementarily, by taking the limits of summation carefully into consideration, that actually the following generating function given above for $k,d$ integers with $d>k$ can be written as

$$(x+t)^k(x+1)^{d-k}=\sum_{p=0}^{d}x^p\sum_{l_1=\max(0,p+k-d)}^{\min(p,k)}t^{k-l_1}\binom{k}{l_1}\binom{d-k}{p-l_1}\doteq\sum_{p=0}^dx^pc_p(t;d,k)$$

One can compute from this generating function the sums in question by setting $t=-1$. There should be no convergence issues even when the powers $k,d$ are non-integers.

Incidentally, the coefficient summands have precisely the functional form of the hypergeometric distribution. Also, miraculously, the support of the summation is also the same. Using known results about the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) and it's generating function we find that, at least for $d-k\geq p$

$$c_p(t;d,k)=t^k\binom{d-k}{p}~_2F_1(-p,-k;d-k-p+1;\frac{1}{t})$$

Of course there are more cases to be investigated, it would be interesting to take a look at them and perhaps edit this post.

$\textbf{EDIT :}~ \text{The case $d-k<p$}$

In this case it turns out that if one shifts summation variable to $l_2=l_1-p-k+d$, we obtain a different expression but still in terms of a hypergeometric function:

$$c_p(t;d,k)=t^{d-p}\binom{k}{d-p}~_2F_1(p-d,k-d;p+k-d+1;\frac{1}{t})$$

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for writing this out.  I'll tentatively keep this post open in case someone has another perspective to consider